# making log2 scaled heatmap in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I want to plot a heatmap of fold changes in matplotlib, where the colors are plotted on a log2 scale, and customize which ticks are shown in the colorbar. I tried the following:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors
from matplotlib.colors import SymLogNorm, LogNorm

mat1 = np.clip(np.random.normal(20, 10, [20, 20]), a_min=0, a_max=500)
mat2 = np.clip(np.random.normal(10, 5, [20, 20]), a_min=0, a_max=500)
mat = np.clip(mat1 / mat2, a_min=0, a_max=500)
plt.figure()
print mat
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap("seismic")
ticks = np.array([1/float(50), 1/float(20), 1, 20, 50])
# how to make these ticks spaced out on a log2 and not log10 scale?
plt.pcolormesh(mat, cmap=cmap, norm=SymLogNorm(linthresh=0.01, vmin=1/50., vmax=50.))
p = plt.colorbar(ticks=ticks)
plt.show()
```

I want fold change of 1 to appear as white so I used the seismic colormap.

**Question:** How can I make the colors spaced in log2 scale, and not log10? And also have the ticks show up as log2 values rather than the unlogged values?

If I try to use `LogNorm` instead of `SymLogNorm` then the tick labels and my ticks do not show up:

```
# This does not work -- ticks do not show
plt.pcolormesh(mat, cmap=cmap, norm=LogNorm(vmin=1/50., vmax=50.))
p = plt.colorbar(ticks=ticks)
```

I know `SymLogNorm` is meant for negative data (which I don't have). I only used it because of this tick issue with `LogNorm`

Comment: If you want to have the logarithms of the values on your colorbar, why don't you just plot the logarithm of your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the `locator` of the `colorbar` object to a `LogLocator` with a base of 2. You then need to call `p.update_ticks()`.

```
plt.pcolormesh(mat, cmap=cmap, norm=SymLogNorm(linthresh=0.01, vmin=1/50., vmax=50.))

p = plt.colorbar()
p.locator=ticker.LogLocator(base=2)
p.update_ticks()
```

[image]

Comment: so does this mean that the difference in color between a log2 unit of 1 and a log2 unit of 2 is two-fold? i.e. unit of 2 is twice as red as unit of 1? (as opposed to unit of 2 is 10x more red than unit of 1)