# A log2 colorbar in matplotlib scatter plot

Tags: matplotlib, colorbar, scatter

I know it is possible to normalize the colors of the data by a log10 as like this

```
plt.scatter(x,y,edgecolors='none',s=marker_size,c=void_fraction,
                norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm())
```

but is it possible to normalize it automatically on a **log2** (not log10) with scatter ?

Thanks.

Comment: you could try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34949536/making-log2-scaled-heatmap-in-matplotlib